# Communication between nodes of two private blockchains

Tags: private-blockchain

How can the nodes on one Ethereum private blockchain send/receive transactions from the nodes operating on another private blockchain?

Answer (score 6):

By design, nodes talk each other **only** if they are on the same Ethereum blockchain (same networkID and genensis block). Maybe you can achieve something like a two-way peg sidechain with two Ethereum blockchain, for example using some adapted relay contracts like [BTC Relay](http://btcrelay.org/).

For completeness, while nodes can't *cross* their own blockchain borders, Ethereum transactions are **not bounded to a specific blockchain** at all, so you **can** actually send the exactly same signed transaction to different blockchains using different client nodes. Indeed, this is why you can send for example a transaction both to the ETH and to the ETC blockchain.